# Can I do this in JPA/Hibernate/Spring?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, design-patterns, jpa

I have a simple hierarchy of objects which starts from the `QuizResponse` object.

First two of these are important:

```
UserPersonalityQuizResponse
   extends PersonalityQuizResponse extends QuizResponse 
UserScoredQuizResponse
   extends ScoredQuizResponse extends QuizResponse 
...
AnonymousPersonalityQuizResponse
   extends PersonalityQuizResponse extends QuizResponse
AnonymousScoredQuizResponse
   extends ScoredQuizResponse extends QuizResponse
```

These two, `UserPersonalityQuizResponse` and `UserScoredQuizResponse`, have a "user" property mapped on a different column for each.

Is it possible to make something in JPA/Hibernate, like an interface, `UserResponse`, to allow me to implement it and then to do this?

```
List<UserResponse> quizResponses = user.getUserQuizResponses()
```

Right now I need to make two queries to get this (on to retrieve `userPersonalityQuizResponses` and one for `UserScoredQuizResponses`).

Unfortunately the hierarchy of the `QuizResponse` class does not allow `UserPersonalityQuizResponse` and `UserScoredQuizResponse` to extend the same parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a HQL query like `from QuizResponse q where q.class = UserScoredQuizResponse or q.class = UserPersonalityQuizResponse`

See more details about polymorphic queries here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#queryhql-polymorphism

Comment: I am afraid this do not work, because I need to query this classes against the "user" property.... org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: user of: com.qfeast.persitence.dao.quiz.QuizResponse